# JWT token parse

Tags: spring-security, token, jwt

please tell me how correct parse JWT token.
I needed get roles...

```
   static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
    if (token != null) {
        // parse the token.
        String user = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody()
                .getSubject();
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                .getBody();
        List<String> roles = (ArrayList<String>)claims.get("roles");
        System.out.println("ROLE IS: " + roles);
        return user != null ?
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, Collections.emptyList()) :
                null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

output ROLE IS: [{authority=ROLE_ADMIN}, {authority=ROLE_USER}
How correct i can doing cast to Collection for use as parameter in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
So the problem was solved...  

List<String> roles = (ArrayList)claims.get("roles");
        for (Object role:roles){
            HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String,String>)role;
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.addAll(map.values());
            for (String item: list) {
                grantedAuthorityList = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(item);
            }
```